# XML Parser Error : Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml

When i try to create xslt out of it is throwing error "SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog."

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CadgrafNITF.xsl"?>
<newsItem guid="urn:newsml:cadgraf.com:12022014:INDIA" version="3"  standard="NewsML-G2" standardversion="2.15"  xml:lang="ta">
<rightsInfo>
    <copyrightHolder uri="http://cadgraf.com/" >
        <name>CADGRAF</name>
    </copyrightHolder>
    <copyrightNotice>
        (c) Copyright 2014 CADGRAF, all rights reserved
    </copyrightNotice>
    <usageTerms>
        Not for use outside the India
    </usageTerms>
</rightsInfo>

<itemMeta>
            <DataEntryDate>2013-12-26T00:00:00</DataEntryDate>
            <PrintDate>2013-12-06T00:00:00</PrintDate>
            <ID>1215</ID>
            <User>006Parthiban</User>
            <Publication>Daily Thanthi</Publication>
            <Edition>SE 2nd Edition</Edition>
            <Location>Bangalore</Location>
            <PageNumber>10</PageNumber>
            <PageType>01 செய்திகள்</PageType>
            <ArticleType>01 செய்தி</ArticleType>
            <edNote>Specify if any notes</edNote>
</itemMeta>

<contentMeta>
    <contentCreated>2013-11-21T15:21:06-05:00</contentCreated>
    <contentModified>No Updations</contentModified>
    <classification1>CT நீதிமன்றங்கள் - COURTS JUDICIARY</classification1>
    <classification2>HC ஐகோர்ட்டுகள் - HIGH COURTS</classification2>
    <geolocation1>TN Tamil Nadu</geolocation1>
    <geolocation2>CO  Coimbatore</geolocation2>
    <title>மனைவியை காப்பாற்ற அப்பாவி பெண் கொலை வழக்கு: வக்கீல்  ராஜவேலுவின்  முன்ஜாமீன்  மனு  தள்ளுபடி ஐகோர்ட்டு உத்தரவு</title>
    <subtitle>மனைவியை காப்பாற்ற அப்பாவி பெண் கொலை வழக்கு: வக்கீல்  ராஜவேலுவின்  முன்ஜாமீன்  மனு  தள்ளுபடி ஐகோர்ட்டு     உத்தரவு</subtitle>
    <dateline>சென்னை, டிச.6</dateline>
    <bodytext>கோவை சிவானந்தா காலனியைச் சேர்ந்தவர் மாரிமுத்து. இவரது மனைவி அம்மாசை. கணவனுக்கும் மனைவிக்கும் இடையே கருத்து வேறுபாடு இருந்து வந்தது. இதனால் இருவரும் பிரிந்திருந்த நிலையில் அம்மாசை மாயமானார். இதுகுறித்து போலீசில் புகார் கொடுக்கப்பட்டது.
```

விசாரணையில், அம்மாசை தனது வக்கீல் ராஜவேலுவை அடிக்கடி சந்தித்து வந்தது தெரிய வந்தது. மேலும் விசாரணையில், வக்கீல் ராஜவேல்தான் அந்த பெண்ணை கொலை செய்தார் என்று விசாரணையில் கண்டறியப்பட்டது. மனைவி மோகனாவின் மீதான மோசடி குற்றத்தில் இருந்து அவரை காப்பாற்றுவதற்காக, அம்மாசையை கொலை செய்துவிட்டு, அதை மோகனா என்று காட்டி ராஜவேல் சான்றிதழ் பெற்றதாக போலீசார் கண்டறிந்தனர்.
இந்த வழக்கில் ராஜவேல், சென்னை ஐகோர்ட்டில் முன்ஜாமீன் கேட்டு மனு தாக்கல் செய்தார். நீதிபதி எஸ்.நாகமுத்து முன்பு நேற்று இந்த மனு விசாரணைக்கு வந்தது. அப்போது அரசு வக்கீல், ஏற்கனவே ராஜவேலுவை கைது செய்துவிட்டதால் இந்த மனு விசாரணைக்கு உகந்ததல்ல என்று கூறினார். அதைத் தொடர்ந்து முன்ஜாமீன் மனுவை நீதிபதி தள்ளுபடி செய்து உத்தரவிட்டார்.
        மனைவியை காப்பாற்ற அப்பாவி பெண் கொலை வழக்கு
        /resources/images/1215_murder_b-imgname.jpg
        கோவை, முன்ஜாமீன், அம்மாசை, வக்கீல், எஸ்.நாகமுத்து
        அப்பாவி பெண் கொலை
        /resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname1.jpg
        வக்கீல்  ராஜவேலு
        /resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname2.jpg
        கோவை சிவானந்தா காலனியைச் சேர்ந்தவர் மாரிமுத்து
        /resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname3.jpg
        நீதிபதி எஸ்.நாகமுத்து முன்பு நேற்று
        /resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname4.jpg
        N/A
        N/A
        N/A
        N/A
        /resources/pdf/1215_murder.pdf

xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
<div style="width: 100%;display:table">
        <div style="width:33%;float:left;text-align:center;">
            <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/itemMeta">           
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Publication: </span> <xsl:value-of select="Publication"/></div>
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Edition: </span><xsl:value-of select="Edition"/></div>
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Location: </span><xsl:value-of select="Location"/></div>
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Page Number: </span><xsl:value-of select="PageNumber"/></div>
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Page Type: </span><xsl:value-of select="PageType"/></div>
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Article Type: </span><xsl:value-of select="ArticleType"/></div>
            </xsl:for-each>

    </div>
        <div style="width:33%;float:left;"><img  style="width:100%;" src="resources/images/dhinathanthi.jpg"/></div>
        <div style="width:33%;float:left;text-align:center;">
            <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/itemMeta">                               
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">ID: </span><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></div>
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Data Entry Date: </span><xsl:value-of select="DataEntryDate"/></div>
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Print Date: </span><xsl:value-of select="PrintDate"/></div>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">                                                        
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Content Modified: </span><xsl:value-of select="contentModified"/></div>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/itemMeta">                                   
                <div style="margin: 0 5px;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Editor Notes: </span><xsl:value-of select="edNote"/></div>
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </div>
</div>

<div style="margin: 20px auto 0 auto;text-align:center;display:table;">
        <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">
        <div style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;float:left;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Classification1: </span><xsl:value-of select="classification1"/></div>
        <div style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;float:left;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Classification2: </span><xsl:value-of select="classification2"/></div>
        <div style="margin: 0 10px 0 0;float:left;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">Location : </span><xsl:value-of select="geolocation1"/></div>       
        <div style="margin: 0;float:left;"><span style="font-weight:bold;">SubLocation: </span><xsl:value-of select="geolocation2"/></div>      
        </xsl:for-each>
</div>

    <div style="width: 100%;display:table">
            <div style="Width: 80%;float: left;border: 0px solid #999;margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;">

                <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">
                    <h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></h1>
                        <div style="border-bottom: 5px solid #999;width:40%;text-align:center;margin:0 auto;"> </div>
                    <h2  style="text-align:center;"><xsl:value-of select="subtitle"/></h2>
                    <h4 style="text-align:center;"><xsl:value-of select="boxtitle"/></h4>
                    <div style="text-indent:25px;text-align: justify;"><span style="margin-right: 10px;font-style:italic;"><xsl:value-of select="dateline"/></span>         <xsl:value-of select="bodytext"/></div>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
            </div>

            <div style="Width: 18%;float: left;border: 1px solid #999;margin: 10px 5px;min-height:300px;padding:3px;">
                         <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">               
                    <h3 style="text-align:center;margin-top:0;">Keywords</h3>
                    <div><xsl:value-of select="Keywords"/></div>
                    </xsl:for-each>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="display:table;margin: 20px auto;text-align:center;">
    <div style="width:14%;float:left;margin-right:10px;">
        <img style="float:left;margin-right: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;" src="resources/images/1215_murder_b-imgname.jpg"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">
        <p style="margin-top:10px;"><xsl:value-of select="boxtitle"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>

    <div style="width:14%;float:left;margin-right:10px;">
        <img style="float:left;margin-right: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;" src="resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname1.jpg"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">
        <p style="margin-top:10px;"><xsl:value-of select="st_boxdesc1"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>

    <div style="width:14%;float:left;margin-right:10px;">
        <img style="float:left;margin-right: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;" src="resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname2.jpg"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">
        <p style="margin-top:10px;"><xsl:value-of select="st_boxdesc2"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>

    <div style="width:14%;float:left;margin-right:10px;">
        <img style="float:left;margin-right: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;" src="resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname3.jpg"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">
        <p style="margin-top:10px;"><xsl:value-of select="st_boxdesc3"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>


<div style="width:14%;float:left;margin-right:10px;">
        <img style="float:left;margin-right: 5px;margin-bottom: 10px;" src="resources/images/1215_murder_otb-imgname4.jpg"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="newsItem/contentMeta">
        <p style="margin-top:10px;"><xsl:value-of select="st_boxdesc4"/></p>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>



        </div>

<h5 style="text-align:center;margin: 5px 0 0 0;">Cadgraf - Archive Indexer</h5>
<h6 style="text-align:center;margin: 5px 0 0 0;">(c) Copyright 2014 CADGRAF, all rights reserved</h6>
<h6 style="text-align:center;margin: 5px 0 0 0;">Not for use outside the India</h6>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the XML declaration is the very first line of the file? Be sure there are no line breaks before it.

Comment: Thanks i converted both the xml declaration into single one and worked for me. But am having another issue unicode fonts are not rendering in browser.

Comment: Make sure you provide <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> in the <head> section of html.